# Need some help converting a MAC address to binary data for use in an ethernet frame

Tags: python, networking, ethernet

I've been looking over various internet postings and a lot of the code I've seen looks similar to this:

```
def mactobinar(mac):
    addr = ''
    temp = mac.replace(':', '')

    for i in range(0, len(temp), 2):
        addr = ''.join([addr, struct.pack('B', int(temp[i: i + 2], 16)))])

    return addr
```

Can someone explain how this code works?

Comment: Any particular part? Or do you want us to read the documentation to you?

Answer (score 4):

Why do people insist on writing all that?

```
def mactobinar(mac):
  return binascii.unhexlify(mac.replace(':', ''))
```

Comment: Why do people insist on writing all that? def mactobinary(mac): return mac.replace(':', '').decode('hex') ;)

Answer (score 1):

[7.3. struct — Interpret strings as packed binary data](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html). That'd be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Ok im not really the best at pythen but ill give it a shot.

when the mac address is passed into `mactobinar` the first thing that happens is that your removing  the semi colon to make a constant string without any delimiters.

So 01:23:45:67:89:ab becomes 0123456789ab

Ok in the next part were looping threw a range, this range here is creating a offset range.

So `range(0, len(temp), 2)` returns an array with the ranges like range(start,max,steps);

then for every value in that array were creating a binary for that integer using struct.pack and also joining it together

Your version
`struct.pack('B', int(temp[i: i + 2], 16)))`

Documanted version
`struct.pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...)`

pack converts an entity into its binary format.

hope this gives you some insight on whats going here

Here are some items to get you started:

http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters

http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.pack